# What's the simplest way to make an alertbox in android?

Tags: android, alert

If I were in javascript I could open an Alert dialog with `alert("Hello world")`

What's the simplest way to make an alert box in Android?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Comment: Here is a link that will help you get started it is very very simple [alert dialog](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/) I hope that helped you.

Comment: Try to google it next time. Here is a link to the android docs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: The question can be definitely short or silly but I don't think it deserves downvote. We're all here to learn

Comment: I don't think the question was downvoted because it was short or "silly", but simply because it showed utter laziness on the part of the asker. If he even had only typed his question into a google search, he would have been inundated with answers and samples.

Comment: I did type it into Google. I got pages and pages and pages of docs and code. I was glad that djechelon was able to answer my question with one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.whatever).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
```

Where

- `this` is an instance of Context (perhaps you are within an `Activity`)
- `R.string.whatever` is defined in `strings.xml` file which I suppose you master like a Jedi until you ask (or perhaps follow tutorials on localization). Can be replaced with a plain old quoted string
- `setPositiveButton` tells that the dialog will have a button that is going to simply dismiss the dialog (notice `null`) and is labeled "OK"